# how to find the max date using 2 join tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please help!!!
I'm using SQL Dev 2.1 and i want to find the latest date with also joining tables. My query is below:-

I want to get the latest DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.TRANSACTION_DATE
as there are more that one date relating to the same invoice number but different comments posted against the DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.DESCRIPTION.

```
SELECT AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLIENT CLIENT,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME CLI_NAME,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PARTNER PARTNER,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PAR_NAME PAR_NAME,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER MANAGER,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE REFERENCE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.STATUS_CODE STATUS_CODE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_DATE INVOICE_DATE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.TIME_BILLED TIME_BILLED,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GROUP_CLIENT_CODE GROUP_CLIENT_CODE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GRPCLI_NAME GRPCLI_NAME,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_BALANCE,
SUBSTR(AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER, 3, 2) CENTRE,
DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.DESCRIPTION,
MAX (BILLING_TRANSACTIONS_V.SEQUENCE_CODE),
DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.TRANSACTION_DATE
FROM AR_INVOICE_INQ_V
LEFT JOIN DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V
ON DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.INVOICE_NUMBER = AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE
JOIN BILLING_TRANSACTIONS_V
ON BILLING_TRANSACTIONS_V.INVOICE_OR_CN_NUMBER = AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE
WHERE AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_BALANCE         >0
AND AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER BETWEEN 'AAAA' AND 'AZZZ'
GROUP BY AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLIENT,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PARTNER,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PAR_NAME,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.STATUS_CODE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_DATE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.TIME_BILLED,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GROUP_CLIENT_CODE,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GRPCLI_NAME,
AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_BALANCE,
SUBSTR(AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER, 3, 2),
DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.DESCRIPTION,
DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.TRANSACTION_DATE;
```

Comment: Can you post your input table structures and desired o/p

Answer (score 0):

Replace your LEFT JOIN with a query that gets the MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) for each INVOICE_NUMBER.

That should give you what you want:

```
select AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLIENT CLIENT,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME CLI_NAME,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PARTNER PARTNER,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PAR_NAME PAR_NAME,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER MANAGER,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE REFERENCE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.STATUS_CODE STATUS_CODE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_DATE INVOICE_DATE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.TIME_BILLED TIME_BILLED,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GROUP_CLIENT_CODE GROUP_CLIENT_CODE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GRPCLI_NAME GRPCLI_NAME,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_BALANCE,
  SUBSTR(AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER, 3, 2) CENTRE,
  DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.DESCRIPTION,
  MAX(BILLING_TRANSACTIONS_V.SEQUENCE_CODE),
  DC.TRANSACTION_DATE
from AR_INVOICE_INQ_V
left join (SELECT INVOICE_NUMBER, MAX(TRANSACTION_DATE) FROM DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V GROUP BY INVOICE_NUMBER) DC on DC.INVOICE_NUMBER = AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE
join BILLING_TRANSACTIONS_V on BILLING_TRANSACTIONS_V.INVOICE_OR_CN_NUMBER = AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE
where AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_BALANCE > 0
  and AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER between 'AAAA' and 'AZZZ'
group by AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLIENT,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.CLI_NAME,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PARTNER,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.PAR_NAME,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.REFERENCE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.STATUS_CODE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_DATE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.TIME_BILLED,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GROUP_CLIENT_CODE,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.GRPCLI_NAME,
  AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.INVOICE_BALANCE,
  SUBSTR(AR_INVOICE_INQ_V.MANAGER, 3, 2),
  DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V.DESCRIPTION,
  DC.TRANSACTION_DATE;
```

Comment: that does not work, i still get a duplicate entry in the debt_collection_steps_V.description column as there are 2 comments entered with different transaction dates. so this gives me duplicate values on the invoice_balance

Comment: Then you'll have to do an INNER JOIN with a query that selects the id and MAX(date) and JOIN it with your current query, But to help you there, you'll have to add more information to your question. I suggest a sqlfiddle with sample data

Comment: You create the sqlfiddle, run it and see that it has no errors, copy the address and put it in your question.

Comment: What i was suggesting was for you to create a sqlfiddle (table structure, sample data) and you put that in your question. Then you add also exactly what are your requirements.

Comment: here is the sample data

Comment: CLIENT CLI_NAME PARTNER PAR_NAME MANAGER INVOICE_NUMBER STATUS_CODE INVOICE_DATE TIME_BILLED GROUP_CLIENT_CODE GRPCLI_NAME INVOICE_BALANCE CENTRE DEBT_DESC SEQ_CODE DEBT_COMMS_DATE
1 abc x mr x 123 987 p 24-Oct-13 1.25 1.1 adcd 2 zz test 1 1234 23-Oct-13
1 abc x mr x 123 987 p 24-Oct-13 1.25 1.1 adcd 2 zz test 2 1234 24-Oct-13

Comment: i want it to only get the latest DEBT_COMMS_DATE being the 24-Oct-13

Comment: I couldn't see the sample data, but I updated my answer. See if that is what you want

Comment: Thank you for your help Filipe but i get an error     Error at Command Line:17 Column:21
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Sorry. There was a trailing ) in there. try again.

Comment: the DC.TRANSACTION_DATE ON HAS ONE ) AT THE END AND NONE AT THE START

Comment: Error at Command Line:29 Column:39
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DC"."TRANSACTION_DATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I'm not sure what problem that is. Try putting doublequoptes around DC and TRANSACTIO_DATE occurrences.

Comment: Can you create a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the tables structure and sample data, so i can see what is wrong?

Comment: COLUMNS CLIENT
CLI_NAME
PARTNER
PAR_NAME
MANAGER
INVOICE_NUMBER
STATUS_CODE
INVOICE_DATE
TIME_BILLED
GROUP_CLIENT_CODE
GRPCLI_NAME
INVOICE_BALANCE
CENTRE
DEBT_DESC
SEQ_CODE
DEBT_COMMS_DATE

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "KPRD"."AC_COMMS_DEBT" ("CLIENT", "CLI_NAME", "PARTNER", "PAR_NAME", "MANAGER", "INVOICE_NUMBER", "STATUS_CODE", "INVOICE_DATE", "TIME_BILLED", "GROUP_CLIENT_CODE", "GRPCLI_NAME", "INVOICE_BALANCE", "CENTRE", "DEBT_DESC", "SEQ_CODE", "DEBT_COMMS_DATE")

Comment: Don't put that here. put it in sqlfiddle and share the address.

Comment: sorry, i've never had to do this before so I'm new to all this

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: put your code to create the tables and insert data into them in the left side of sqlfiddle. select oracle from the list of servers, and then click build schemma. When everything builds correctly, copy the link of the page here.

Comment: sorry, i still don't know how to do that

Comment: Sorry man. In order to help you further, re read my previous comment and see [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e390)

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO WITH THIS SQLFIDDLE

Comment: You put there the sql to create a replica of your tables: AR_INVOICE_INQ_V, BILLING_TRANSACTIONS_V, DEBT_COLLECTION_STEPS_V. Then you insert some sample data in the tables that you can get from your tables.